# UIWebview set text on current textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, barcode

Is there a way to set the text on the current textfield on a `UIWebview`?

I don't need to retrieve the text. I don't need to determine what text field currently has focus.

Basically the user will scan a barcode (with the linea-pro) and if there is a textfield selected in the uiwebview I just want to set the text to the retrieved barcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exec JavaScript function that can set value to text field. Something like this

```
NSString *text = @"Text field text";
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var textField = document.activeElement;"
                                                   "textField.value = '%@';"
                                                   "document.activeElement.form.submit();", text];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Comment: But this assumes you know the ID of the text field? I just want to say "hey whatever the current text field... put this value in." (almost like I'm indirectly controlling the keyboard)

Comment: This works (I used activeElement)
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var textField = document.activeElement;"
                            "textField.value = '%@';", text];

Comment: If you change your answer to reflect this string I will mark it as correct. 
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var textField = document.activeElement;"
                                                       "textField.value = '%@';" 
                                                        "document.activeElement.form.submit();", text];

Comment: The only time this doesn't work is if I use the camera to scan barcodes because the UIWebView looses focus. Any ideas for a work around?

Answer (score 1):

```
 let javaScriptQuery = "document.activeElement.id"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptQuery) { (result, error) -> Void in
            print("focus element id = \(result as? String)")
            let focusedElementID = (result as? String)!
            let testString = "Testing Testing......"
            let javascript = "var textField = document.getElementById('\(focusedElementID)'); textField.value = '\(testString)';"
            self.webViewObj.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { (result, error) in
                if error != nil {

                } else {
                    print(result ?? "not found")
                }
            }
        }
```